# Issue passing props to great-grandchild components using ReactLayout in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm just wondering what the best way is to complete this React task.
Say, I have a component like this one:

```
App = React.createClass({
  //mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  // Initial State declared here.
  getInitialState() {
    return {};
  },

  proxyState(state) {
    console.log(`Triggered proxyState, top-level: ${state}`);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.layout}
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

I need to be able to pass down `proxyState(state)` to a great-grandchild component, where the child (and grandchild) will be rendered using `ReactLayout`.

As an example, here's a bit of code from FlowRouter showing how I'm currently rendering the component(s) that are involved with this chain:

```
FlowRouter.route('/proxies', {
  name: 'proxies',
  action() {
    const content = <ProxyPage />;
    ReactLayout.render(App, {
      title: 'Proxies',
      layout: <MainLayout content={content} />
    });
  }
});
```

The content renders just fine, but what I don't understand how to do is pass `proxyState()` down to `<MainLayout />` (and subsequently, `<ProxyPage />` that will be rendered inside it, and then `<ProxyForm />`, which gets rendered inside that.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to the concept of passing props around, and I guess this might be a semi-advanced thing for someone who has been writing React stuff for maybe 3 days now.  Thanks in advance!

If anyone's needing to look at the rest of my code to get an idea of what I'm looking for, the project is (currently) in a public repository:  https://bitbucket.org/czbaker/karuto

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to pass props to children is to literally directly pass them:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.myProp}</div>
    );
  }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return (
      someProp: "I'm a prop value!"
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Child myProp={this.props.someProp} />
    );
  }
});
```

Assuming you have a tree family structure, you can just have the parents keep passing down the props you need them to pass down.

However, the above can get a bit tedious, especially if you want to send a prop to every layer in a deep tree. To make life simpler, React has a concept called `context`s. These allow you to specify a prop to be available to all children of a parent prop, regardless of depth.

I'm not going to copy/paste the example from the docs, so go check it out here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html and feel free to ask questions :)